# .PHP without Apache

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, cgi

I am fairly new so firstly please excuse me if I am doing anything wrong.

I have build a website for my friend, using the same techniques as I used for my own, yet with his host the .php files are not being read/picked up.

> > Is PHP a CGI or Apache module?
>
> PHP runs as a cgi at Duport Associates Limited – this is because it is
>   more secure than running it as an Apache module (if it runs as an
>   Apache module PHP runs as the same user with the same rights as
>   Apache).
>
> This means that php_value directives in .htaccess files will not work
>   - however we do allow local php.ini (or php4.ini for php4) files - these are plain text files that allow php.ini directives to control
>   PHP for scripts in the directory where the file is placed, and its
>   subdirectories.
>
> Additionally, .htaccess directives such as AddHandler .php x-httpd-php
>   will break your PHP scripts.

^^ I get this message when searching their help page.

At this moment my code looks like this:

```
<?php include('http://www.amberstoneinc.co.uk/php/html/start.php'); ?>

<?php include('http://www.amberstoneinc.co.uk/php/head/index.php'); ?>

<body class="index">

    <div class="container">

        <?php include("www.amberstoneinc.co.uk/php/nav/en.php"); ?>

        <div class="index-section">

            <?php include("http://www.amberstoneinc.co.uk/php/content/index.php"); ?>

            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>

    <?php include("http://www.amberstoneinc.co.uk/php/bg/index.php"); ?>

</body>
```

Can someone please help by explaining what I should do?

Comment: Why you include URLs and not just the path like this: include ('bg/index.php'); ?

Comment: How do I fix it? If you go to the website: www.amberstoneinc.co.uk you can't see anything.. and it doesn't seem to pick up my .php files

Comment: It probably just means that the script *crashes* because `include`ing other files by their complete URL is disabled/doesn't work. `include` files by their file path, not with the complete URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are attempting to `include` via a full URL. Not only is this a very bad idea and the functionality will likely be disabled (I would hope it is anyway), it would most likely not do what you expected even if it did work.

Your code should be (educated guess, may not be exactly right) this:

```
<?php include('./php/html/start.php'); ?>

<?php include('./php/head/index.php'); ?>

<body class="index">

    <div class="container">

        <?php include("./php/nav/en.php"); ?>

        <div class="index-section">

            <?php include("./php/content/index.php"); ?>

            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>

    <?php include("./php/bg/index.php"); ?>

</body>
```

To learn exactly why this is, you should read [this](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) thoroughly.

In order to see a useful error message when things go wrong, you should add this to the top of the page while developing:

```
<?php ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL); ?>
```

Comment: Follow on Question: How do you go back with <?php include("./php/content/index.php"); ?>

Asin, if you are already on the page www.address.com/about.. how do you link it to the file www.address.com/php/menu.php?